# How to enable click on view that is hidden behind a column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a compose view that has a header on top, and scrollable column with Tabs and horizontal pager with lazy column. The issue I'm having is I'm not able to consume click evens on `Header` because `column` is on top of the header. Is there a way to consume click event on a button that lives in header which is behind the column?

```
Surface {

   val scrollState: ScrollState = rememberScrollState()

   Box {

      Box { Header() }

      Column(
         modifier = Modifier
              .fillMaxSize()
              .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
      ) {
          
          Spacer(Modifier.height(headerHeight))
          
          TabLayout() {...}
          HorizontalPager(
              Modifier.height(screenSize).nestedScroll(
                            remember {
                                object : NestedScrollConnection {
                                    override fun onPreScroll(
                                        available: Offset,
                                        source: NestedScrollSource
                                    ): Offset {
                                        return if (available.y > 0) Offset.Zero else Offset(
                                            x = 0f,
                                            y = -scrollState.dispatchRawDelta(-available.y)
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
          ) { LazyColumn {...} } 
      }
   }
}
```

I'm aware that I can move the `Box { Header() }` inside of the column and replace it with `Spacer()`. This works fine, but i can't get the animation effect that I want with this approach; where list is scrolling on top of the header and header is collapsing slowly to give parallax effect.

Comment: Share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a screenshot of the UI.